# Shapefiles won't overlap due to projection problems

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system

I have a two shapefiles. One of neighborhoods and one of points. The point file was originally a spreadsheet of X,Y coordinates. but have been exported to shapefile. They display but not over the neighborhood shapefile like they should. I've tried `reprojecting`,  `project tool` and `define projection`. It still will not overlap. Everything is displaying in US (Feet). What is wrong? Using arcmap 10.4

Here are the projection data in the Layer source:

Point file: 
`Projected Coordinate System:   NAD_1983_StatePlane_Pennsylvania_South_FIPS_3702_Feet
Projection: Lambert_Conformal_Conic
False_Easting:  1968500.00000000
False_Northing: 0.00000000
Central_Meridian:   -77.75000000
Standard_Parallel_1:    39.93333333
Standard_Parallel_2:    40.96666667
Latitude_Of_Origin: 39.33333333
Linear Unit:    Foot_US`

`Geographic Coordinate System:  GCS_North_American_1983
Datum:  D_North_American_1983
Prime Meridian:     Greenwich
Angular Unit:   Degree`

Neighborhood file: 
`Projected Coordinate System:   NAD_1983_StatePlane_Pennsylvania_South_FIPS_3702_Feet
Projection: Lambert_Conformal_Conic
False_Easting:  1968500.00000000
False_Northing: 0.00000000
Central_Meridian:   -77.75000000
Standard_Parallel_1:    39.93333333
Standard_Parallel_2:    40.96666667
Latitude_Of_Origin: 39.33333333
Linear Unit:    Foot_US`

`Geographic Coordinate System:  GCS_North_American_1983
Datum:  D_North_American_1983
Prime Meridian:     Greenwich
Angular Unit:   Degree`

Here's a sample of the Lat Long Coordinates:

`Lat1`        `Long1`
`39.93128729`   `-75.14691545`
`39.93130836`   `-75.14711798`
`39.93143481`   `-75.14845446`
`39.93144498`   `-75.14853968`
`39.93117173`   `-75.14714819`
`39.93099668`   `-75.14705857`
`39.9310071`    `-75.14715449`
`39.93101477`   `-75.14725051`
`39.93119391`   `-75.14848865`

Comment: Do you know what coordinate systems your XY table and your neighborhood file were in before you started? All those projection tools are worthless unless you know what coordinate system your data was in to start with.

Comment: @DanC positive that the neighborhood file was exactly what I listed it to be. The point file was originally a csv that I did display csv on. Let me know how else I can provide information to figure this out.

Comment: can you add a few X,Y values from the Point csv? to verify it is Stateplane?

Comment: @klewis added the lat long coordinates. Couldn't figure out how to make the column heading matched :/

Comment: You need to define the point shapefile as NAD 1983, EPSG:4269 because the coordinates are in decimal degrees. THEN you can use the Project Tool to convert the coordinates to the SPCS zone.

Comment: @mkennedy I searched for "SPCS zone" in the "Project Data Management"  tool wizard but didn't find it. nothing came up.

Comment: Sorry! Look under state plane, NAD 1983 (US feet) for Pennsylvania South. SPCS is state plane coordinate system.

Comment: @mkennedy Can you possibly explain how you arrived at that response?Thanks again!

Comment: I'm not writing an answer, because there are other Q&A on site about this (too lazy to search for them). If two layers don't line up, often one has an undefined or misdefined coordinate reference system. I look at the coordinates. Small values like yours are decimal degrees, so couldn't be in a projected CRS.